image detection and segmentation
This is the originale image
This is the expected outcome
I have tried using the canny edge detection, and the best i could get from this is that i was able to segement only the objects that are not on the border of the image, but i need every singele objecct in the image to be included and filled.
But this is what i am getting
how could i acheive the expeccted outcome, please

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.
